# Heroku clone ssh error

Tags: git, heroku

I wanted to clone my heroku app to my work machine.

What happens is:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a myapp
Cloning from app 'myapp'...
Cloning into myapp...
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My public keys are set and uploaded correctly. So I assume what happens is, that my firewall is blocking port 22. I have no access to it though, since McAfee Enterprise is installed and can only be configured by extern administration. Contacting them and getting a temporary change through would last several days (if they do it at all...) and probably cost some nerves.

Is it somehow possible to clone my app to local or to some rep. without using ssh port 22? Or any other quick solution?
What do?

Comment: If you already set up a git:remote with: `heroku git:remote -a myapp`, why dont you just pull the repo with `git pull heroku master`

Comment: also you need to login with `heroku login` if you havent already

Comment: @Senjai the pull throws me the same error as it forces a ssh connection aswell.

Comment: Did you login to heroku first? using heroku login in terminal?

Comment: @Senjai Of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

try if you can connect via ssh (no git, just plain ssh) to this/any host.

if that does not work and you want a quick&dirty solution, clone somewhere else and copy the clone via other means. e.g. clone on a server and copy via ftp or clone on your laptop and copy via usb-stick.

Comment: ssh throws me a "Permission denied." error. The dirty solutions are not an option for me, because of file system complications.